# rewrite url, remove segment

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove /uploads from a url. I have followed many examples but none of them work.

I think this one is the closest and should actually work but nothing is happening.

```
RewriteRule ^/uploads/(.+)$ /$1 [QSA]
```

here is what I have in the htaccess

```
# Enable URL rewriting for pretty URLs

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/uploads/(.+)$ /$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule !\.(php|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|cgi|pdf|doc|xls|docx|xlsx|ppt|tff|svg|eot|woff|swf|mp3|wma|wav|MP4|AIFF|AAC|m4a|m4p|AVI|MOV|MPG|MPEG)$ index.php [NC]
#RedirectMatch ^/$ /misc/offline.php [NC]
```

I should go from:
    http://example.com/storage/uploads/droom.pdf
To:
    http://example.com/storage/droom.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
RewriteRule ^/uploads/(.+)$ /$1 [QSA]
```

with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?uploads(.*)$ /$1$2 [L]
```

Comment: oh ofcourse, it didn't start with /uploads .. and .* is better then .+ i guess? Is working now, thanks.